# Interpretation of descriptive statistics for dummy variable

Tags: categorical-data, interpretation, descriptive-statistics

How can I describe descriptive statistics for a dummy variable (gender of worker in a shop)? Let's say this is the info that I have:

```
mean :         0.47
median :       0
max :          1
min :          0
std. dev :     0.4998
skewness :     0.101
kurtosis :     1.01
jarque bera : 85.67
probability :  0
```

I know that some of the information is useless since it's a dummy variable. So how do I interpret it in words?

Comment: 47% of observations are coded as 1?

Comment: Just a side tip, don't name dichotomous variables this way. Instead of calling it "gender," call it "male" or "female." That way you'd know what 1 (aka Yes) stands for. If this is "male," then you can easily figure out 0.47 is the fraction of males.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think only one descriptive statistic is needed: "47% are male" (assuming 0 encodes female and 1 encodes male). No other statistics are really helpful to describe those data. If you thought these were a randomish sample of a larger population, you could compute the confidence interval for that proportion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the frequency table summarizing the number of ones/zeros would be a good summary by itself. Mean seems to be the only reasonably explainable statistic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use descriptive stats, "describe" or "describe.by" for numerical and frequency tables for categorical / dummies.